# Understanding Sorting algorithm for C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm studying for my GNU C test that I have on Friday. On the review there's a question that I cannot understand. "The following algorithm sorts an array into ascending order in place.  The algorithm is sensitive to the order of the contents being sorted (random, sorted order, reverse sorted order).  Evaluate the algorithms performance numerically in terms of the exact number of compares and exchanges required for minimum and maximum run time performance.  What will its overall performance be in Big “O” notation for the performance as N approaches ∞.  You must support your answer analytically to receive credit.  How do keys with the same value on algorithm entry appear when the sort is complete?"

```
//Sort Grades in ascending order by locating grade[0], then grade[1], etc.
   void AscendingSort( int intArray[ ], int numInt){
    for(int j = 0; j < numInt - 1; j++ ){
      for(int k = j + 1; k < numInt; k++ ){ 
          if( grades[ j ] > grades[ k ] ){ 
             int temp = grades[ j ]; 
             grades[ j ] = grades[ k ];
            grades[ k ] = temp;
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

So I believe this is a bubble sort and the complexity would be O(N) for best case which is sorted order. For worse case which is reverse order and for random order it'll be O(N^2). So how do I exactly calculate that? How do I actually calculate the number of comparisons and exchanges from the information given? Also if you can walk through the sort algorithm that would be greatly appreciated, I'm having a hard time understanding this. :( thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is not a bubble sort but a selection sort.

Comment: *"if you can walk through the sort algorithm"* - use pencil and paper to simulate the execution of the code with a short array (5-6 elements should be enough). This is the best way to understand how it works.

Comment: A note about O(N) and bubble sorts. In order for a bubble sort to finish in O(N) time, it needs to have **early termination code**. In other words, if the bubble sort detects that no swaps were needed on a particular pass through the array, then it immediately exits both loops. Since the code in your question has no way to exit the loops early, it will always run in O(N^2) time. And of course, as @ MikeCAT said, the code shown is not actually a bubble sort.

Comment: @MikeCAT    How do you know it's selection sort, because to me it looks like bubble sort. I also have wrote it down on paper, but I confuse myself going through the temp. Besides that's only half of my question, how can you calculate the comparisons and exchanges from the information given? From the algorithm given, how can you find the best, worst and average cases?

Comment: @ImranAli  ^^read comment I posted up.

Comment: @user3386109 ^^ read comment up. I also understand that as well for bubblesort. So what sort is this exactly?

Comment: @axiac  ^^read the comment I posted above.

Comment: This is [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) because each elements are compared with the first element in the range dealed with and the minimum element in the range is extracted. Only adjacent elements will be compared in [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: What is what *you* call "a bubble sort"?

Comment: I would say it's a poorly implemented selection sort. One of the primary benefits of a selection sort is that it minimizes the number of swaps. The code in the question makes lots of unnecessary swaps, so it's a non-standard algorithm. I suspect that you were given a non-standard algorithm was so that you would have to do the analysis yourself.

Comment: @MikeCAT so how can I calculate the number of comparisons and exchanges from what is given?

Comment: @user3386109 How can I calculate the number of comparisons and exchanges from what is given? How would I be able to find the complexity? I know Time = comparisons + exchanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to know difference between bubble sort and selection sort.

- **[Selection Sort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Selection_sort)**: Sorting is done by comparing all the elements with the first element. Then further repeat it with second element and so on.
- **[Bubble Sort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Bubble_sort)**: Sorting is done by comparing two adjacent indexes of an array.

For calculating complexity consider `numInt = 5`

Now, start considering from the innermost loop here:

```
k = 0+1=1; k<5
```

This loop will go on until `k` evaluates to `4` and when `k=5` the loop ends and no comparison is made. Thus the loop executes from `k=1` to `k=5`, i.e 5 times which = intNum times.

Now consider the outer loop here:

```
j = 0; j<4
```

This loop will go on until `j` evaluates to `3` and when `j=4` the loop ends and no comparison is made. Thus the loop executes from `j=0` to `j=4`, i.e 5 times which = intNum times.

For the nested loop we multiply the complexity of loops. hence it evaluates to

```
intNum*intNum = intNum^2
```

and `O(intNum^2)`.

Refer to [these further details of complexity evaluation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-of-algorithms-set-4-analysis-of-loops/).

Comment: Your definition for selection sort is a little confusing (and wrong). In selection sort you divide the array into two sections - sorted and unsorted, initially all unsorted. You repeatedly select the smallest element (hence the name) from the unsorted section and place it at the end of the sorted section. Comparing everything with the first element is not, in general, how you find the smallest element.